# Powder Problems Snowboarding

Tags: technique, snowboarding

This is a big issue that I am having when I am doing snowboarding runs on powder. Usually, when there is fresh powder from overnight or accumulation during the day, I tend to "trip over" and lose my balance over accumulated powder debris. What type of skills/drills can I do to make sure that this does not happen ?

I am able to do powder turns just fine in green level but when at times, It is really easy for me to pick up speed and lose control where I just trip over. When it gets to blue and black runs, I tend to really have this issue of tripping over since the snow is much deeper. While at really steep runs, I tend to do a turn (say toe turn) and while switching to my heel turn, I tend to traverse horizontally with my board and fall on my butt. Could someone provide some advice on how I can get better ?

I also tried to lean back but didnt exactly shift the bindings to the back (but could this really make that large of a difference) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I always found that having my bindings set slightly back on the board (leaving you with more tip length than tail length) makes a big difference in deeper powder. It gives you a little more confidence in being able to keep your nose out of the powder and "hydroplane" ("snowplane" ?) on the surface. I always rode the Burton EST bindings on the rail system whenever I could so I could shift them just slightly without much effort. You can always have a separate board set up for powder but that kind of requires you to commit to one or the other for the day.

Also, whereas you want to keep your weight a little bit forward on groomed slopes, you want to shift your weight slightly backwards in your stance. Nothing extreme, because that will also yield problems, but only as much as you would shift forward on groomed stuff.

One last thing that's helped me, and I'm not sure its a common thing or just something I've come across, if you start feeling yourself sinking in, do a gentle dip-and-jump thing. Kind of mimicking the motion you would do to start your spring at the end of a diving board. I think it sort of compacts the snow under you just slightly, ushering your board back up over the top of that and back up around the surface.

Most importantly in powder however, is be sure of your terrain under the surface. Powder is a ton of fun and a great place to learn (always nicer dumping it backwards in powder than on packed down slopes). Just know it's a lot different from hoping off a chairlift and bombing the main lines.